# Get approx value from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to get the "Distance" value for a given "LapTimeSeconds" that isn't present in the table, is there any way to do that?

Maybe using interpolation? But how? Thanks in advance

```
# Something like this?
driver1_tel.loc[(driver1_tel["LapTimeSeconds"] == (3.0)]
```

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use scipy's interpolate function on the columns of interest. From looking at what you have written it would go something like:

```
from scipy import interpolate
x = df.LaptimeSecond
y = df.Distance
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
ynew = f(3)
```

The variable ynew would give you the interpolated distance for a laptime of 3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! Just started playing with data